# How to have text reminder popup when receiving calls from specific contacts?

Tags: contacts, calls, tasker, android-10, productivity

Use case: I would like to be able to add a note that is displayed the next time a certain person calls. For example when "Joe" calls it shows me a note such as "Joe has peanut allergies" or "I owe him $20" etc.

How can I do this? Is there an app? I have Tasker. I could have Tasker launch my standard note taking app when calls are received but I don't know how it could open the specific note for each person.

Comment: Similar question: [Any Android app to display a user-entered note when a contact calls](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241746/44325) (surprisingly asked at very near timing)

Comment: [A paid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nikanorov.callnotespro)// More apps from [Izzy's list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_917) //Haven't tried these myself