# Display a user-entered note when a contact calls

Tags: applications, notifications, contacts, call-screening, caller-id

In android is there a way to display a user entered note specific to a contact whenever that respective contact calls? Something like this...
[image: Contact Specific Note]

For context, it has to be similar to how Truecaller app displays the contact details of an incoming call including name, phone number and location.
[image: TrueCaller]

Can your method/app/solution be used with VoIP/messaging apps like Signal, WhatsApp, Telegram, Zoom etc?

> Notes:
>
> 1. Any solution (app/tasker profile etc) that can be run on a standard Android device is welcome.
> 2. Unlike Truecaller app it need not work with phone numbers that are not in user's contact list but user must be able to write notes for
>    individual contacts in their contact list.
> 3. FOSS solutions are preferred.
> 4. Solutions that run on non-rooted devices are preferred (for more accessibility)

Comment: Similar question: [How to have text reminder popup when receiving calls from specific contacts?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/241745/44325) (surprisingly asked at very near timing)

Comment: [See this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241745/how-to-have-text-reminder-popup-when-receiving-calls-from-specific-contacts#comment321662_241745)